# Getting text from all <a> tags via vba

Tags: html, css, vba

I have to get the urls for all the posts in a given page from a forum

I observed that the source code has the following structure

```
        <h2 class="message-subject">            <span class="lia-message-unread">

                <a class="page-link lia-link-navigation lia-custom-event" id="link_168" href="/t5/p12345">
                    me and myself

                </a>
                        </span>         </h2>            </div>
```

I want to extract the href part of each  tag present inside each "MessageSubjectIcons" div

How would i achieve that using vba?

I can access the url of the page i need to visit, but how do i save the html into a variable and keep accessing it?